# Execute backward query with JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a query function in my repository:

`fun findStockholderIndividualByPersonFirstNameContainsOrPersonLastNameContains(firstName: String?, lastName: String?): MutableList<StockholderIndividual>?`

It works to some extent.

However `StockholderIndividual` is a part of a class called `Register` which has attribute called `reference`

I want to include in the query a way to say `WHERE Register reference = 'XXXXX'`

Is this possible with JPA?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It can be possible, use @Query annotation before the method in repository and write sql script.
for example:

```java
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.status = 1")
List<User> findAllActiveUsers();
```